# Is there a use to L'Hopital rule for $*/∞$ when the function in the numerator doesn't converge?

Tags: functions, derivatives, convergence-divergence

When studying the L'Hopital's rule for limits in the case of $*/∞$, we studied that the rule applies when the function in the denominator appraoches $∞$, regardless to the limit of the function at the numerator.

Usually, this rule is used in the case of $∞/∞$ or $-∞/∞$, but I was wondering if there are other uses, since it's supposed to apply no matter what is the function in the numerator.

If the function in the numerator converges to a real number $L$, then by arithmetic of limits, the limit of the fraction will be zero.
But, if the function on the numerator does not converge, it could be interesting to try to use L'Hopital's rule to find the limit.

Nonetheless, I could not find a non-converging funtion to put in the numerator, that one can caclulate the limit of the fraction using L'Hopital (for example when using sin or cos variations, affter differentiating I still remained with $\sin$ or $\cos$ and could not find a limit).

I would love to hear if someone knows an example of such function, that shows there is a use for L'Hopital other than $\pm∞/∞$.
Thank you!

Comment: When the function $f(x)$ in the numerator is bounded then we don't need l'Hospital to deduce from $g(x)\to\infty$ what $f/g$ does.

Comment: That's true. But there are non-converging funtions that aren't bounded.

Comment: As we know:  l'Hospital's rule assumes that both function either converge to zero or diverge to $\pm\infty\,.$ The answer to your question should then be obviously no. If you want to tackle an example where $f$ is unbounded and does not converge you may want to try your luck with $\limsup f$ and $\liminf f\,.$ Don't expect me to formulate that "theorem" for you.

Comment: @KurtG.: l'Hospital's rule (as formulated in Rudin's *Principles*, for example) requires only that the limit is of type “zero/zero” or “anything/infinity”. It's not necessary to have “infinity/infinity”. So I think this is actually a very good question.

Comment: An example for the numerator would be helpful. As far as I understand, you want functions $f,g$ with $f/g$ such that $g$ tends to infinity and $f$ is unbounded but neither tends to $\infty$ nor $-\infty$. Would an example for your question be $f(x)=x\cdot\sin(x)$ as $x\to\infty$? It's not bounded but also oscilates between positive and negative values.

Comment: @vitamind: To find an example to which l'Hospital applies, you need to give not just the numerator $f$ but also a matching denominator $g$ which tends to infinity, and is such that $f'/g'$ has a limit (finite or infinite).

Comment: Dear @HansLundmark, I am well aware of that. My question was not adressed to you but at the OP as I'm trying to understand what his goal is. It doesn't seem clear to me.

Comment: @vitamind: As I interpreted the question, the goal is precisely to find an example like that.

Comment: @vitamind The goal is exactly as Hans pointed out :)
I was just curious about whether L'Hopital's rule is usefull for other cases other than +-∞/∞, and trying to find an example when f doesn't converge and isn't bounded to make it an interesting example when the answer isn't simply zero (and there is need for L'Hopital).

Answer (score 3):

If the expression $f$ in the numerator does not converge to $\pm\infty$, then necessarily there is a sequence of inputs such that $f$ converges to a (finite) limit.  Therefore if the limit of the ratio exists, it would have to be zero.  Then the result could be that the limit exists (and is $0$) if and only if trying to apply l'Hopital's rule we get a quotient of derivatives which tends to $0$.